# Auto Mapper throwing error on mapping virtual property of data object to business object

Tags: c#, repository, automapper

I am using auto mapper and able to map my data objects to business objects with out any issue. But when i try to map data object that is having virtual property, it is throwing error:

> AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException:'Unable to create a map expression from AdmissionStatu.AdmissionStatusLookup to AdmissionStatus.AdmissionStatusLookup'

My business object is:

```
public class AdmissionStatus
    {
        public long AccountID { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Comment { get; set; }
        public AdmissionStatusLookup AdmissionStatusLookup { get; set;}
    }
```

My data object is:

```
 public partial class AdmissionStatu
    {
        public long AccountID { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Comment { get; set; }   
        public virtual AdmissionStatusLookup AdmissionStatusLookup { get; set; }
    }
```

My query in repository is:

```
var query = from rows in dataContext.AdmissionStatus
                        where rows.AdmissionID == admissionId
                        select rows;
return ToBusinessObjects(query);
```

This is auto mapper mapping configuration:

```
protected virtual IConfigurationProvider CreateAutomappingConfiguration()
        {
           return new MapperConfiguration(c =>
            {
                c.CreateMap<DataType, BusinessType>();
                c.CreateMap<BusinessType, DataType>();
            });
        }}
```

and `ToBusinessObjects` method is:

```
 protected List<BusinessType> ToBusinessObjects(IQueryable<DataType> query)
        {
            return query.ProjectTo<BusinessType>(mappingConfig).ToList();
        }
```

When ever i call query, i am getting error in `ToBusinessObjects` method. I am using same set up for mapping all data objects to business objects and vice-versa in the same way and it is working fine. But when i am mapping objects having virtual property it is not working. Could some one help me what went wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
return Mapper.Map<List<BusinessType>>(query.ProjectTo<BusinessType>(mappingConfig).ToList())
```

Comment: The virtual property `AdmissionStatusLookup` has one more virtual property to it. Does it matter here?

Comment: AM doesn't care about virtual properties :) Maybe you're missing a map.

Comment: Well `AdmissionStatusLookup` has 2 more virtual properties. So, i mapped them by overriding my base class method `CreateAutomappingConfiguration()` with additional mapping of virtual properties. Then my Auto Mapper started to map my entity.

Comment: I changed my query to: `var query = from rows in dataContext.AdmissionStatus
                        where rows.AdmissionID == admissionId
                        select rows;
return ToBusinessObjects(query.ToList());` and my `ToBusinessObjects` method to         `protected List<BusinessType> ProjectToBusinessObjects(IEnumerable<DataType> query)
        {
            return query.AsQueryable().ProjectTo<BusinessType>(mappingConfig).ToList();
        }` and as said i added all virtual property mappings of `AdmissionStatusLookup`. With all these changes i was able to get what i wanted.